# How the Substitution of the 3rd to the last occurrence using SED command works?

Tags: unix, sed

Let's consider the 'file.txt',
[click for the file contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt4sr.png)

I want to substitute the 3rd to the last occurrence of "p".

```
sed -E 's/(.*)p((.*p){2})/\1@\2/' file.txt
```

Here, "p" is substituted by "@".
I want to know how it works.
Can anyone explain me ?

Comment: look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean ... though `sed` doesn't exactly have greedy quantifier, for this regex, it will be similar... `()` is capture group and `\N` is backreference..

Comment: short answer: `/.*p/` will match till last `p` in the line... `/(.*p)(.*p)/` here first group will match till last but one `p` (assuming at least two p in input) and the second group will then have rest of content till last `p`.. and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `sed`
- `-E` - Use extended regex. Compatible with GNU and BSD sed.
- `'` - quote the argument.
- `s` - substitute

  - `/` - separator
  - `(` - start first group
  - `.*` - match anything.
  - `)` - end first group.
  - `p` - match `p`. Effectively, first group will contain all characters from the line up until a `p`.
  - `(` start second group.
  - `(` start third group. Notice the order.
  - `.*p)` match anything up until a `p` ...
  - `{2}` ... two times. So effectively, this will make sure there are at least two `p` in the rest of the line.
  - `)` close second group. So second group will contain something, a `p`, something and a `p`.
  - `/` separator. Next comes replacement.
  - `\1` - backreference to first group. So is substituted for all character from the beginning of the line up until first `p` without the `p`.
  - `@` - a `@`
  - `\2` - backreference to second group. So is substituted for all characters after the first `p` without it, the second `p`, something between second and third `p` and the third `p`.
  - `/` separator
- `'` - end single quote.

The `(.*p){2}` means the same as `.*p.*p`

Comment: Great downvotes!

Comment: thanks for the answer but still i am confused

Comment: let's consider the line 4

Comment: according to you the first group "(.*)" means all the characters starting from the line followed by a "p". So here the 1st group ends. Till now understood but after that I can't get it.

Comment: confused about the ((.*p){2}).

Comment: `( .. )` is used to "remember" everything inside. `(.*p){2}` is equal to `.*p.*p`. The `.` matches any character. The `*` matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding pattern. The `.*` matches any character zero or more times. You can find many, many, many, many resources online that try to explain regular expressions. I recommend crossword puzzles, they are amazing and fun.